# What does "ignoring attributes on template argument" mean in this context?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I've been tasked with eliminating the warnings in a largish C++ project, most of which I did not write, and one of the more common warnings is emitted for things like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<DIR, decltype(&closedir)> dir(opendir(dirToDelete.c_str()), closedir);
```

The warning is

```
ignoring attributes on template argument 'int (*)(DIR*) {aka int(*)(__dirstream*)}' [-Wignored-attributes]
std::unique_ptr dir(opendir(dirToDelete.c_str()), closedir);
```

(`DIR`, `opendir`, and `closedir` are all defined in the standard header `dirent.h`.)

I know what this code does, and it is working, but what does the warning mean? What is the attribute that the compiler is referring to that is ignored, and what are the implications of that?

Comment: please show a [mre] including the compiler version and compiler flags

Comment: if it's because your declaration of `closedir` has the `__nonnull((1))` attribute then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833602/remove-attribute-from-a-function-pointer-or-reference to remove it (or just ignore/disable the warning)

Comment: A "workaround" (which might be better BTW), is to create a custom deleter class, instead of having function pointer.

Comment: *"what does the warning mean?"* The function pointer won't have the attribute, so any check (no_discard, check non-null argument, ...) it provides won't be applied to the function pointer call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The attribute which is being ignored is likely [GCC's `nonnull`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-nonnull-function-attribute), which indicates that parameters cannot be null pointers. You can reproduce this warning with the following code:

```cpp
#include <memory>

void closedir(struct DIR*) __attribute__((nonnull(1)));

std::unique_ptr<struct DIR, decltype(&closedir)> dir(nullptr, &closedir);
```

```
<source>:5:48: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'void (*)(DIR*)' 
               [-Wignored-attributes]
    5 | std::unique_ptr<struct DIR, decltype(&closedir)> dir(nullptr, &closedir);
      |
```

The problem is that the attributes of a function pointer are discarded when being used as template arguments. If you kept using function pointers, you would have to get rid of the attribute (see [Remove __attribute__((...)) from a function pointer or reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73833602/5740428)), or you would have to suppress the warning (see [Selectively remove a warning message using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925179/5740428)).

#### Solution

In general, you should not create smart pointers where the deleter is a function pointer, because that increases the size of the smart pointer<sup>1)</sup>, and prevents optimizations<sup>2)</sup>. You are creating a `std::unique_ptr` that can hold a deleter with the same signature as `closedir`, but the deleter could be any function in principle.

Instead, prefer custom types as deleters:

```cpp
#include <memory>

// Exposition-only, obviously use #include <dirent.h>
void closedir(struct DIR*) __attribute__((nonnull(1)));


// Note 1: In C++20, you could also decltype(lambda) as a deleter type.
struct closedir_deleter {
    // Note 2: Consider adding noexcept.
    void operator()(struct DIR* d) const {
        closedir(d);
    }
};

// Note 3: You can create a type alias for this specialization of std::unique_ptr.
// Note 4: It is no longer necessary to pass a deleter as an argument to the
//       constructor, because the deleter is default-constructible, and not a pointer.
std::unique_ptr<struct DIR, closedir_deleter> dir;
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cPqdcYWEY)*

Not only is this better practice, it also gets rid of the warning for you.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *This is because `std::unique-ptr` has to store the pointer itself, as well as the function pointer. For simple empty deleters, it doesn't have to store anything.*

<sup>2)</sup> *Function pointers cannot be optimized into direct function calls if the compiler doesn't know their exact value. Function pointers are known to be inlined poorly in general.*

Comment: Could help me with the same problem using the standard stdio calls? I have now: `std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), &pclose);`. I don't define FILE or pclose myself.

Comment: That exact problem is what brought me here `std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), &pclose);` works for me.  Although I'll take the advice here and implement a `deleter` as a functor as in the example.